# Power Functions on the Integers

Tags: real-analysis, integer-lattices

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of the form $f(x)=x^a$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. If $f(\mathbb{Z})\subset\mathbb{Z}$, show that $a\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Source: A friend posed this problem; not sure if it is well known.

Comment: $a$ is nonnegative!

Comment: I am correcting the problem statement, thank you.

Comment: Wasn't this a Putnam problem? Maybe I'm thinking of something else though.

Comment: @Alex, 1971 A6: "Let $c$ be a real number such that $n^c$ is an integer for every positive integer $n$. Show that $c$ is a non-negative integer." See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33109/contest-problems-with-connections-to-deeper-mathematics

Comment: See: http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html

Comment: Also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69737/contest-problems-with-connections-to-deeper-mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cite [DoctorBatmanGod](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43798/doctorbatmangod):

The answer to this question can be found on this [link](http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html) .