# If any integer to the power of $x$ is integer, must $x$ be integer?

Tags: exponentiation

My apologies if this has been asked already, I've searched but couldn't find it...

Let $x$ such that for every $y \in N$, $y^x$ is an integer. Does that necessarily mean that $x$ is an integer?

Comment: If $y$ is a perfect square then let $x=0.5$.

Comment: @M.Knight Um, huh?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17560/if-2x-and-3x-are-integers-must-x-be-as-well and also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33109/contest-problems-with-connections-to-deeper-mathematics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question was question A6 in the 1971 Putnam competition. A solution using finite differences and the Mean Value Theorem can be found [here](https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html). You may also be interested in this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17560/21564) which discusses a vast generalisation which shows that if $2^x$, $3^x$, and $5^x$ are integral, so is $x$. As established in the answers to the MO question, it is still an open problem as to whether knowing $2^x$ and $3^x$ are integral is enough to deduce that $x$ is integral.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! There is a famous problem which says that if $2^\alpha$, $3^\alpha$ and $5^\alpha$ are integer numbers, then $\alpha$ is a natural number.

Unfortunately I don't remember proof and the reference I know is not in English.

Comment: That's a special case of the Six Exponentials Theorem, and the proof is long & hard. But the question we have here is not that hard. It was on the Putnam exam in 1971, and solutions to Putnam questions are available in various places.