# Interesting claim concerning real numbers. How to prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, integers

How to prove the following claim ?

> $a$ is a fixed real number such that $n^a$ is an integer for all natural number $n$. Then , $a$ is an integer.

Please try this problem, I am having problems solving it.

Comment: You just mentioned that $n$ is a natural number........

Comment: may be we need to prove\disprove that $a$ is integer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's already been answered.

Comment: Do you mean prove/disprove that $a$ is an integer? Other than that it would be helpful to provide some contex, where did you encounter this problem, your attempts on this problem etc.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel If it is a duplicater then close it as duplicate (and add the link to the answered question)

Comment: @miracle173 Metaphorically, I mean. In the comments.

Comment: I haven't seen it in this site earlier, guys try it, its nice

Comment: Why all the close votes? Link to the duplicate if it exists please. And sure, the post is lacking own work, but the question itself is interesting.

Comment: @ArpanSadhukhan what  a your question about this problem? From the title and a comment of yours I get the impression you might just be posing a question which you already know the answer to, and so you don't actually face a problem. This is not what our site is about (although it might be a fit for puzzling.se)

Comment: It is elementary that if $a$ is rational then $a$ is an integer. And the Gelfond theorem implies that $a$ cannot be  an irrational algebraic number. But .......

Comment: My solution uses exponential sums. Anyone have a more elementary solution?

Comment: @Kyle If memory serves, there is a classic elementary argument by Erdős, and that's why many others believe this to be a duplicate.  I hope the dupe is found soon :).

Comment: @Kyle My mistake, the Erdős result (at least the one I had in mind) was that if $f(n)$ is increasing and multiplicative then it must be $n^a$ for some $a>0$.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858893/if-any-integer-to-the-power-of-x-is-integer-must-x-be-integer

Comment: a solution: https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html