# Is it true that if $\frac{\log m}{\log n}=\frac{\log 3}{\log 2},m,n\in \mathbb N$ then $m=3^k,n=2^k,k\in \mathbb N$?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Is it true that if $\dfrac{\log m}{\log n}=\dfrac{\log 3}{\log 2},m,n\in \mathbb N$ then $m=3^k,n=2^k,k\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: How did you get to that conclusion?

Comment: @Don Thousand Someone asked me,I think it's true but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation can be rewritten to read
$$
\log_nm=x=\log_23
$$
for some real number $x$. So $3=2^x$ and $m=n^x$. If we write $n=2^y$, it follows easily that $m=3^y$. This brings us to the real question of whether both $2^y$ and $3^y$ can be integers for the same choice of $y\notin\Bbb{N}$.

But according to the material covered in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/858955/11619) that is an open question.

Comment: CWfying for I am not adding anything new to the site. I could vote to close as a duplicate, but I am uncertain whether that is prudent. This is not such a frequent question.