# Connections of Putnam and IMC with research in Mathematics

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

Is it true that some problems from Putnam and IMC have connections to Mathematics at the research level and it's necessary to use techniques at that level to solve them ? If so, could someone give me examples of Real Analysis problems of this type ?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but what are putnam and imc?

Comment: They are Mathematics competitions for undergraduates

Comment: @R_D Putnam refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Lowell_Putnam_Mathematical_Competition and IMC refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mathematics_Competition_for_University_Students

Comment: Yes, some Putnam problems have connections to Mathematics at the research level. No, it's never necessary to use techniques at that level to solve them. See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69737/contest-problems-with-connections-to-deeper-mathematics and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33109/contest-problems-with-connections-to-deeper-mathematics